# Using the stdout and stdin with System.IO.runCommand

Tags: haskell, systems-programming

I am trying to capture the stdin and stdout from [runProcess](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/process/latest/doc/html/System-Process.html#v%3arunProcess) into a string for analysis.

However, setting up the handles seems to be rather difficult.  I wandered into GHC.IO.Handle, and that seems to be the logical destination, but it *seems* that this should be very simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need to communicate with the process interactively, the easiest method is to use [`readProcess`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/process/latest/doc/html/System-Process.html#v:readProcess):

```
> readProcess "date" [] []
  "Thu Feb  7 10:03:39 PST 2008\n"
```

Otherwise, look at [`runInteractiveProcess`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/process/latest/doc/html/System-Process.html#v:runInteractiveProcess) - it starts the process and creates pipes that you can write to and read from with e.g. [`hPutStr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-IO.html#v:hPutStr)/[`hGetLine`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-IO.html#v:hGetLine).

Comment: readProcessWithExitCodeSource turns out to be what I was looking for.